# Input range должен окрашиваться в выбранный цвет. на js

Tags: javascript, input, range

Нужен был слайдер для выбора цвета. Нашёл решение и немного изменил: https://codepen.io/hobuttt/pen/zLoyWx
Проблема в следующем: ползунок должен окрашиваться в выбранный цвет.
В найденном варианте используется:

```
if (typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined') {
            var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
            stylesheet.insertRule('input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb { background: ' + bkgColor + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
        } else {
          document.styleSheets[0].addRule('input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb', 'background-color: ' + bkgColor);
        }
```

Но в реале это не работает :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обращение через querySelector тоже не срабатывает. 
Есть у кого-то варианты, как это можно решить?

Comment: Если вы ищите кроссбраузерное решение, то нативный input type=range не подходит. Я в аналогичном случае использую SVG.

Comment: А почему в codepen этот код отрабатывает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вижу проблемы, код рабочий. При необходимости, добавьте правила для IE. 
 Учтите также, что во всех браузерах, кроме префиксов, сильно разнится то, как применяются стили. Например, в Хроме `border` расположен внутри ползунка, а в Мозилле снаружи.

```js
// safari needs window.onload
window.onload = function() {

  // create a <canvas> element to hold the color gradient
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  // range is 208-40=168, add 1 so range value stays inside the canvas
  canvas.width = 169;
  canvas.height = 1;
  // create a 2d context
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  // create linear gradient specify x,y,width,height
  var gradient = canvasContext.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // define colors to add - can use any color format but must be in quotes
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "#ff0000");
  gradient.addColorStop(.17, "#ff00ff");
  gradient.addColorStop(.33, "#0000ff");
  gradient.addColorStop(.50, "#00ffff");
  gradient.addColorStop(.67, "#00ff00");
  gradient.addColorStop(.83, "#ffff00");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "#ff0000");
  // use the gradient as a fill
  canvasContext.fillStyle = gradient;
  // draw the fill onto the canvas, specify x,y,width,height
  canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var thumb = document.getElementById("slider");
  // updates the thumb colors while you drag the thumb, not sure why 'drag' event didn't work here
  thumb.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    changeColors();
  });
  // if 'mousemove' is too fast sometimes value and color won't
  // match up with thumb position, so update just in case
  thumb.addEventListener('change', function() {
    changeColors();
  });

  // display initial value
  var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
  circle.innerHTML = thumb.value;

  // amount to increment/decrement
  // google's metronome uses 2, 3, and 4 steps
  var steps = 2;

  // decrement when minus is clicked
  var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
  minus.addEventListener('click', function() {
    thumb.value = Number(thumb.value) - steps;
    changeColors();
  });

  // increment when plus is clicked
  var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
  plus.addEventListener('click', function() {
    thumb.value = Number(thumb.value) + steps;
    changeColors();
  });

  //    run it once to set colors
  changeColors();

  // set the rgb values from <canvas> using x, y coordinates
  function changeColors() {
    //range starts at 40 so subtract 40
    var xCoord = thumb.value - 40;
    // get the color data from the canvas
    var rgbValues = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(xCoord, 0, 1, 1).data;
    var bkgColor = "rgb(" + rgbValues[0] + ", " + rgbValues[1] + ", " + rgbValues[2] + ")";
    // display thumb value
    circle.innerHTML = thumb.value;
    // set colors
    circle.style.backgroundColor = bkgColor;
    minus.style.color = bkgColor;
    plus.style.color = bkgColor;
    // dynamically change color of thumb pseudo-element by adding new styles
    // test for Firefox API or else thumb won't change colors
    var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    if (typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined') {
      stylesheet.insertRule('input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb { border-color: ' + bkgColor + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
    } else {
      stylesheet.addRule('input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb', 'border-color: ' + bkgColor);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#slider {
  width: 420px;
}

#minus,
#plus {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
}

#slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff0000 0%, #ffff00 17%, #00ff00 33%, #00ffff 50%, #0000ff 67%, #ff00ff 83%, #ff0000 100%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

#slider::-moz-range-track {
  width: 420px;
  height: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff0000 0%, #ffff00 17%, #00ff00 33%, #00ffff 50%, #0000ff 67%, #ff00ff 83%, #ff0000 100%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

#slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px
}

canvas {
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="range">
  <span id="minus">&minus; </span><input id="slider" value="128" type="range" min="40" max="208" step="2"><span id="plus"> &plus;</span>
</div>
```

Ещё было замечено (в версиях браузеров более ранних, чем актуальные), что при стилизации нативных элементов, лучше использовать не общие свойства (например, `border: width style color;`), а разбивать на отдельные (`border-width: ...` и т.д.)